# How do I add to cart more than one of the same item in the serializer (post)?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make this app where I can select the items I want to buy. I want to add two cakes to the cart, for example, but so far I can't select more than one. How do I do that? The field I need to change is 'food' since this one has options like 'cake', 'pastries', etc. I want the user to be able to add as many of each item as they want. I tried with many=True but something is not working out.

This is the serializer so far:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'


class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is the model:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    food = models.ManyToManyField('Food', related_name='order', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.food
```

Comment: can you clarify the "select" process, is that something like "add to cart" feature?

Comment: question not clear?

Comment: @Sumithran I edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: @daneilJames I edited it. I mean something like 'add to cart'.

Comment: so you mean you want to enable user to select  cake, pasta, rice in one click?

Comment: @daneilJames No, I want the user to be able to select as many cakes and pastas as they want. Say they want 2 cakes and 2 pastas, they can do that, but there's no limit or minimum.

Comment: I  think you need bulk_create() in my opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231235/discussion-between-daneil-james-and-satoru).

Answer (score 1):

you will need to add a model where you can add the quantity of an item that you can order:

```
class OrderFood(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"
```

and then you can add or remove an item (or type of food) to/from the order in the views:

```
class AddToCartView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        item_id = request.data.get('id', None)
        if item_id is None:
            return Response({"message": "Invalid request"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=item_id)

        order_item = OrderFood.objects.filter(item=item,user=request.user)

        if order_item.exists():
            order_item = order_item.first()
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
        else:
            order_item = OrderFood.objects.create(item=item,user=request.user)
            order_item.save()
```

not 100% sure about the code ,you'll need to verify it, hope that could help